# Is $\mu_0$ as described countably additive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be a measure space. Define $\mu_0:\mathcal M\to[0,\infty]$ by $\mu_0(A)=\sup\{\mu(B):\mu(B)<\infty,B\subset A\}$. Is this $\mu_0$ countably additive? I could show finite additivity.

Here's the problem when I try to show countable additivity:

Let $A_n\in\mathcal M$ be disjoint then given $\epsilon>0$, for each $n$ get $B_n\in\mathcal M$ with $\mu(B_n)<\infty$ and $\mu(B_n)>\mu_0(A_n)-\dfrac{\epsilon}{2^n}$.

Note that as $A_n$ are disjoint, $B_n$ also are disjoint. So summing over $n$ on both sides,

$$\mu(\cup_n B_n)=\sum_n \mu(B_n)>\sum_n \mu_0(A_n)-\epsilon$$

Now I would love to say $\mu(\cup_n B_n)\leq \mu_0(\cup_n B_n)\leq \mu_0(\cup_n A_n)$ but I can't use the first inequality since I don't know that $\sum_n\mu(B_n)<\infty$.

Comment: But you can argue that $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n) \le \mu_0(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$ for every $N$, by the same argument, right? And then take the limit as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for the hint.